# How to use multiclassification model to make predicitions in entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow

I have trained multiclassification models in my training and test sets and have achieved good results with SVC. Now, I want to use the model o make predictions in my entire dataframe, but when I get the following error: `ValueError: X has 36976 features, but SVC is expecting 8989 features as input.`

My dataframe has two columns: one with the categories (which I manually labeled for around 1/5 of the dataframe) and the text columns with all the texts (including those that have not been labeled).

```
data={'categories':['1','NaN','3', 'NaN'], 'documents':['Paragraph 1.\nParagraph 2.\nParagraph 3.', 'Paragraph 1.\nParagraph 2.', 'Paragraph 1.\nParagraph 2.\nParagraph 3.\nParagraph 4.', ''Paragraph 1.\nParagraph 2.']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

First, I drop the rows with `Nan` values in the `'categories'` column. I then, create the document term matrix, define the `'y'`, and split into training and test sets.

```
tf = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=word_tokenize)
X = tf.fit_transform(df['documents'])

y = df['categories']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Second, I run the SVC model getting good results:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
svm = SVC(C=0.1, class_weight='balanced', kernel='linear', probability=True)
model = svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('accuracy:', model.score(X_test, y_test))

y_pred = model.predict(X_test) 

print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Finally, I try to apply the the SVC model to predict the categories of the entire column `'documents'` of my dataframe. To do so, I create the document term matrix of the entire column `'documents'` and then apply the model:

```
tf_entire_df = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=word_tokenize)
X_entire_df = tf_entire_df.fit_transform(df['documents'])

y_pred_entire_df = model.predict(X_entire_df)
```

Bu then I get the error that my `X_entire_df` has more features than the `SVC` model is expecting as input. I magine that this is because now I am trying to apply the model to the whole column `documents`, but I do know how to fix this.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Why are you refitting the ``CountVectorizer``  named ``tf_entire_df``? Couldn't you just use ``tf`` ?

Comment: Hello! I changed the tf names to differentiate. 'tf' fits the column 'documents' after having dropped NaN values in the column 'categories', so I can train the SVC model. 'tf_entire_df' fits the entire column 'documents' so I can use the model to predict the categories of documents to the whole dataframe.

Comment: So why are you interested in predicting NaN values? If this is your intent, replace all the values with a known placeholder string, like ``'unknown'`` and fit it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In the first fit, I dropped the NaN values (because I manually labeled only part of the documents into categories) to train the model SVC to learn how to assign the documents into categories. Now I have my whole dataframe with all documents (including those that have not been manually labeled by me - hence why the NaN values). I would like to use the trained SVC model to label the remaining documens with no labels for me, but I am having problems applying the trained algorithm in the whole dataset. Hopw that my explanation is clearer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These issues usually comes from the fact that you are feeding the model with unknown or unseen data (more/less features than the one used for training).

I would strongly suggest you to use  [`sklearn.pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) and create a pipeline to include preprocessing (`CountVectorizer`) and your machine learning model (`SVC`) in a single object.

From experience, this helps a lot to avoid tedious complex preprocessing fitting issues.